# While loop not working

Tags: java, arrays, loops, arraylist, while-loop

Hi I am fairly new to java and trying to familiarize myself to it by doing some exercises online.
How do i properly code the while loop so that everytime the user input is wrong it asks the same question again and does not proceed to the next line of code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Array {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner dataIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        int entries = 0;
        List<Integer> grade = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        System.out.println("Enter number of students? ");
        entries = dataIn.nextInt();
        boolean checker = true;
        while (checker){
        for (int i = 0; i < entries; i++){

            int input;
            int addToList;
            System.out.println("Enter grade for student: ");
            input = dataIn.nextInt();
            grade.add(input);

            if (input >= 0 && input<= 100) {

            }else {
                System.out.println("invalid input try again..");
                checker = false;
            }
        }
        }

        int sum = 0;
        int count = grade.size();
        double mean;
        for (int grades : grade){
            sum+= grades;
        }
        mean =(double)sum/count;

        System.out.println("The Grades are: " + grade);
        System.out.println("The number of elements in the Array is " + grade.size());
        System.out.println("The average is: " + mean);
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want `checker` to be `true` when they `invalid input try again..`?

Comment: `checker = true;`  in other case it should false

Comment: oh so thats what i did wrong. I really new to loops and i'm just studying how they work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is backwards. You want the loop to continue if the input is incorrect. There are two ways to fix this:

1. Change `while(checker)` to `while(!checker)`
2. Change `checker=false` to `checker=true` after printing the error message. And set `checker=false` in the `if` branch.

It might help if you change the name of your `checker` variable to something that reads more directly. For example `isInputCorrect` reads very nicely when you write `while(!isInputCorrect)` and it also makes it more clear what the values of `true` and `false` represent.

Comment: Thanks for the answering and giving an advise as well!

Comment: @Onedaynerd Please accept the answer which you find the most helpful when you are able to.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
boolean checker = true
for(int i=0;i< entries;i++){
    int input;

    System.out.println("Enter grade for student: ");
    input = dataIn.nextInt();
      while(checker){
          if(input >= 0 && input<= 100){
               grade.add(input);
               checker = false;
            }else{
              System.out.println("invalid input try again..");
           }
       }
 checker = true;
 }
```

Comment: you forgot to take the input .. this will be an infinite loop of println's

Comment: yeah, sorry about that. why is there an infinite loop?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Array {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner dataIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        int entries = 0;
        List<Integer> grade = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        System.out.println("Enter number of students? ");
        entries = dataIn.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < entries; i++) {
            int input;
            do{
                input = dataIn.nextInt();
                if (input >= 0 && input <= 100) {
                    grade.add(input);
                }else{
                    System.out.println("invalid input try again..");
                }
            }while(!(input >= 0 && input <=100));
        }
        dataIn.close();
        int sum = 0;
        int count = grade.size();
        double mean;
        for (int grades : grade) {
            sum += grades;
        }
        mean = (double) sum / count;
        System.out.println("The Grades are: " + grade);
        System.out.println("The number of elements in the Array is " + grade.size());
        System.out.println("The average is: " + mean);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of doing while(checker)

make a loop for while(running) 
then send it to the keyboard.nextInt()
if its the wrongAnswer than it will loop, if its correct than set running to false
and have code that follows the while loop